# Comment does not define a no-argument constructor. If you are using ProGuard, make sure these constructors are not stripped

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

When I start to click the comment activity, it is showing the error:

com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Class org.w3c.dom.Comment does not define a no-argument constructor. If you are using ProGuard, make sure these constructors are not stripped.

```
public class CommentActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private CommentAdapter commentAdapter;
    private List<Comment> commentList;

    private EditText addComment;
    private CircleImageView imageProfile;
    private TextView post;

    private String postId;
    private String authorId;

    FirebaseUser fUser;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_comment);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Comments");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        postId = intent.getStringExtra("postId");
        authorId = intent.getStringExtra("authorId");

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        commentList = new ArrayList<>();
        commentAdapter = new CommentAdapter(this, commentList, postId);

        recyclerView.setAdapter(commentAdapter);

        addComment = findViewById(R.id.add_comment);
        imageProfile = findViewById(R.id.image_profile);
        post = findViewById(R.id.post);

        fUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        getUserImage();

        post.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(addComment.getText().toString())) {
                    Toast.makeText(CommentActivity.this, "No comment added!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    putComment();
                }
            }
        });

        getComment();
    }

    private void getComment() {

        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Comments").child(postId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot Snapshot) {
                commentList.clear();

                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : Snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Comment comment = Snapshot.getValue(Comment.class);
                    commentList.add(comment);
                }

                commentAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError Error) {

            }
        });

    }

    private void putComment() {

        HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Comments").child(postId);

        String id = ref.push().getKey();

        map.put("id", id);
        map.put("comment", addComment.getText().toString());
        map.put("publisher", fUser.getUid());

        addComment.setText("");

        ref.child(id).setValue(map).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(CommentActivity.this, "Comment added!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(CommentActivity.this, task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private void getUserImage() {

        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(fUser.getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot Snapshot) {
                User user = Snapshot.getValue(User.class);
                if (user.getImageurl().equals("default")) {
                    imageProfile.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
                } else {
                    Picasso.get().load(user.getImageurl()).into(imageProfile);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError Error) {

            }
        });

    }
}


public class CommentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CommentAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<Comment> mComments;

    String postId;

    private FirebaseUser fUser;

    public CommentAdapter(Context mContext, List<Comment> mComments , String postId) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mComments = mComments;
        this.postId = postId;
    }

    public CommentAdapter(CommentActivity mContext, List<org.w3c.dom.Comment> commentList, String postId) {

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.comment_item, parent, false);
        return new CommentAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        fUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        final Comment comment = mComments.get(position);

        holder.comment.setText(comment.getComment());

        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(comment.getPublisher()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);

                holder.username.setText(user.getUsername());
                if (user.getImageurl().equals("default")) {
                    holder.imageProfile.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
                } else {
                    Picasso.get().load(user.getImageurl()).into(holder.imageProfile);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        holder.comment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("publisherId", comment.getPublisher());
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        holder.imageProfile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("publisherId", comment.getPublisher());
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                if (comment.getPublisher().endsWith(fUser.getUid())) {
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext).create();
                    alertDialog.setTitle("Do you want to delete?");
                    alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Comments")
                                    .child(postId).child(comment.getId()).removeValue().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Comment deleted successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        dialog.dismiss();
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });

                    alertDialog.show();
                }

                return true;
            };
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mComments.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public CircleImageView imageProfile;
        public TextView username;
        public TextView comment;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            imageProfile = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_profile);
            username = itemView.findViewById(R.id.username);
            comment = itemView.findViewById(R.id.comment);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You should the no-argument constructor in your "Comment" class.